# How can I allow users to associate their account with a Wikipedia account?

Tags: authentication, oauth, wikipedia

Is there any kind of API (oAuth?) for this? Or maybe a publicly visible piece of information that only the user can edit so that I can give her a hash to put there (similar to how one confirms domain ownership through CNAMEs).

Answer (score 1):

Interesting problem. I'm not aware of any OAuth or other authentication APIs provided by Wikipedia. I have seen tools that relied on the presence of a particular sub-page of User_username to verify that a user gives permission for something (see [this edit counter tool](http://toolserver.org/~soxred93/pcount/), for example) but that relies on the convention, not the technical limitation, that users not edit each others' pages.

On the other hand, users can make edits while logged in, which you should be able to verify. You could ask a user to edit a particular page (in your own user space, say) while logged in to their Wikipedia account and include a particular hash in the comment field. I'm not a Wikipedia security expert, but I don't know of a way to spoof someone else's username in the edit logs.